# How to split information on different tables within one report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I need to display the information of the Main Report in two tables, each of them containing data filtered based on a condition X (1- Bigger than X, 2 - Smaller than X). I tried to create separate data-sets for each table but it leads to an increase on time load. How can I fill different tables within the report, with different filtered information based on main report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a field `listRecords` of type collection with all your records, you can define the table datasource as :

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
    Collections2.filter($F{listRecords}, new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final Integer input) {
            return input > 2;
        }
    })
)
```

Using the `guava library` to filter the collection.

Comment: How can I create the collection type field with all my records ?

Comment: @AlbanoVito But you dont have the data on your report yet?